# Compare pandas two different pandas dataframe to extract the difference

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, analysis

I have two pandas dataframes and I want to compare them to see what the differences are. df1 has a column of all unique IDs, a column of text data, and a column of numeric data. df2 has the same structure but it contains multiple records of the same IDs. I want to take a specific ID from df1 and its corresponding columns then compare it to all the matching IDs in df2 and their corresponding columns. Then i want to take the difference and put them into new df3.

EDIT: df3 should not have rows from df1 if it does not exist in df2

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'ID':['L1', 'L2', 'L3', 'L4'], 'Text':['1A', '1B','1C','1D'], 'Num':[1, 2, 3, 4]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
print(df1)
```

| ID | Text | Num |
| --- | --- | --- |
| L1 | 1A | 1 |
| L2 | 1B | 2 |
| L3 | 1C | 3 |
| L4 | 1D | 4 |

```
data2 = {'ID':['L1', 'L2', 'L3', 'L1', 'L2', 'L3'], 'Text':['1A','1B','1C','2A','2B','1C'], 'Num':[1, 2, 3, 11,2,123]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
print(df2)
```

| ID | Text | Num |
| --- | --- | --- |
| L1 | 1A | 1 |
| L2 | 1B | 2 |
| L3 | 1C | 3 |
| L1 | 2A | 11 |
| L2 | 2B | 2 |
| L3 | 1C | 13 |

I want the out put to looks like:

| ID | Text | Num |
| --- | --- | --- |
| L1 | 2A | 11 |
| L2 | 2B | 2 |
| L3 | 1C | 123 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an outer merge with indicator:

```
(df1.merge(df2, how='outer', indicator=True)
    .loc[lambda d: d.pop('_merge').eq('right_only')]
 )
```

Output:

```
   ID Text  Num
4  L1   2A   11
5  L2   2B    2
6  L3   1C  123
```

*NB. If you need to keep the index, `reset_index()` before merge, then `set_index('index')` afterwards.*

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate the dataframes and discard all duplicate rows.

```py
pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but when i run this i get records from from df1 that are not in df2. i need records from df1 that are not in df2 to be removed for my final df3